# In browser why facebook.com automatically call https://www.facebook.com even after deleting cache/history

Tags: http, redirect, https, browser-cache, hosts

In my /etc/hosts I have added an entry to point www.facebook.com to my local ip address.
Now even after deleting complete cache/browser history, why typing www.facebook.com calling https://www.facebook.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

As [Troy Hunt](https://www.troyhunt.com/understanding-http-strict-transport/) explains:

> This is Chrome saying “I’m not even going to issue that
>   request, instead I’m going to change it to HTTPS then try again” which
>   is what gives us the second request. This is key: Chrome has refused
>   to issue the first request over the insecure HTTP protocol.

*Note the similarity to what you are describing - it automatically changed `http` to `https`.*

HSTS protects against man in the middle attacks. You pointing `facebook.com` at localhost, is *basically* a man in the middle attack.

https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+hsts shows how to disable it if necessary. Or https://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/bypass-facebooks-hsts-0169414/ may work to bypass it.